# How to pass data from grandchild to parent component in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components

I have a form (Parent) which contains an input field (Child), which gets its value from a reference table (Grand-grand-child) that is displayed as a modal (Grand-child) which opens up by clicking a button attached to the input field. This is a nested structure that roughly looks like this:

[image]

I need to set the value of the input field by selecting a row in the reference table and confirming my choice with a button "SET VALUE", which means I need to pass data three levels up from Grand-grand-child to Parent through Grand-child and Child.

My state is kept in the Parent component. Is there a simple way of achieving that without using external libraries? Please offer a solution using Hooks as all of my components are functional components.

Here is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-fast-jckfl

See CreateRate component where:

- CreateRate.jsx is the Parent
- InputField.jsx is the Child
- DataFetchModal.jsx is the Grand-child
- Airports.jsx is the Grand-grand-child

Comment: Just pass a state setter function all the way from the Parent down to Grand-grand-child. inside the GGC, create another state that holds the currently selected row. Attach the Parent function mentioned above to the "Set Value" button and, when clicked, call it with the currently selected row. If you showed some code, it's be trivial to demonstrate it.

Comment: I have added my code. What I do NOT understand is whether or not I need to pass the call-back function call up from the GGC to P through the other components in the middle and whether or not the function calls should be the same or different in each component? If I only add the callback function call to the button on the Modal (GC) how would that button know that the value in the Table (GGC) has been selected?

Comment: You won't be passing any functions back up. You simply call a reference to the function that cascades down from the parent. Piece of cake. The thing you need to make clear now is how are your table rows selected? Is there a checkbox on each row or a select button. I know there is that "Set value" button, but how would a row be selected before clicking the confirmation button?

Comment: I am using a BootstrapTable library which has a clickToSelect property that gives me the row props that I can pass back up when selected. That is not a problem. What I don't get is how I can get those props upon selection of the row from the Table (GGC) to the Modal's button (GC) and from there to the Form (Parent). Can you expand on that?

Comment: It's hard to explain it without showing you the changes needed. Is there any chance you could put at least a basic version of your app into Codesandbox.io? Just use some hardcoded sample data. I bet I could make it work for you in 5 minutes. It's just gonna take a long time for me to put it all together from scratch.

Comment: Please see my codesandbox

Comment: Nothing renders. It says "A sandbox error occurred, you can refresh the page to restart the container." And the same error is thrown when you refresh. I also noticed you put up your backend part there as well. There is no need to do that, you can just hardcode some sample data right into your fron end app.

Comment: I have updated the link

Answer (score 0):

Pass a change handler function from parent (where state lives) down to the grand child. The grand child should call this change handler when clicking the Set Value button.

If this is too much prop drilling

- look into component composition first
- if that doesn’t work out, look into context api

**Update**:
You mentioned your problem was trying to access the state inside Grand-grand-child from your Grand-child. In this case you can lift the state up (to Grand-child). This means lifting 'airports' up to DataFetchModal. Here is more info on lifting state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up

Also, it appears you are running into these problems because your code is very nested and not very composable. I would suggest looking into how you could better break up your components. One way to accomplish this is using compound components.

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/compound-components-with-react-hooks

Determining how to break this up better would take some time. However, just looking at this briefly. You may be able to move your DataFetchModal to your parent. Pass a callback to the InputField to fire it off and send the identifying parameters (what input called it). Then, from the parent, compose in whatever modal body using composition. It appears you have a lookup object (objType) inside DataFetchModal. Maybe this could go away by using composition (not sure, and probably separate topic).

**Update 2:**
I pulled down your code sandbox and made a few changes that may help access parent level state. I moved the modal into the parent. Check it out.

https://github.com/nathanielhall/Test

Comment: The SET VALUE button is not part of the Grand-grand-child. It is part of the Grand-child (one level up from the Grand-grand-child).

Comment: Got it! Sorry, I totally missed that. I reviewed your code and from what I can see, you should be able to simply lift state up. In this case the 'airports'. Does this work for you?

Comment: After reading your post again, I'm not sure you can simply lift the state to the modal. If not, then I would suggest breaking up the component better (see my update). If you put the code into a code sandbox or like, I can help you better.

Comment: Your first link is to React.js official dox, which only describe class components, while mine are functional. I will look into the second option of moving the Modal to the Parent. But this will entail too much re-writing of the already otherwise working code. I was hoping I'd be able to access state in Airports from the Parent...

Comment: The idea of lifting state is same for class and function components. It’s fundamental to how react works. You cannot access state directly in child. You can pass functions to manipulate state inside child component, but to “access state”, you must lift it out

Comment: By the way, move the code to code sandbox and I (and others) may be able to help more.

Comment: Appears the link is broken. I’m getting the code sandbox not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229903/discussion-between-denis-and-nathan-hall).